# Create a MatPlotLib using python object

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to convert a Python object into the MatPlotLib graph. 
The python object is coming via a pickle file.

When the pickle file name - 'tstpickelFile' (which has the data to be transformed) is printed, this is the output -

```
[
OrderedDict([('_time', '2019-11-05T14:39:00.000-08:00'), ('count', '711'), ('_span', '60')]), 
OrderedDict([('_time', '2019-11-05T14:40:00.000-08:00'), ('count', '2823'), ('_span', '60')]), 
OrderedDict([('_time', '2019-11-05T14:41:00.000-08:00'), ('count', '2731'), ('_span', '60')]), 
OrderedDict([('_time', '2019-11-05T14:42:00.000-08:00'), ('count', '2752'), ('_span', '60')]),
OrderedDict([('_time', '2019-11-05T14:42:00.000-08:00'), ('count', '655'), ('_span', '60')])
OrderedDict([('_time', '2019-11-05T14:42:00.000-08:00'), ('count', '1233'), ('_span', '60')])
]
```

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import pickle
from collections import Counter
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.style.use("fivethirtyeight")

infile = open('tstpickelFile','rb')
new_dict = pickle.load(infile)
# print(new_dict)
infile.close()

time = []
count = []

top5 = itertools.islice(new_dict, 5)

for eachDict in top5: 
    for key, value in eachDict.items():
        if(key=="_time"):
                time.append(value)
        if(key=="count"):
                count.append(value)

plt.plot(time, count)

plt.title('Time Count graph')

plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('count')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Currently, there are a few issues -

1. The x-axis only shows 711, 2823, 2731, 2752, 2581. I want the x-axis to show 0, 100, 200, 300, 400 (consistent intervals). In this way, the line chart will not be a straight line (as it is currently). Rather it would be a waving line.
2. The time should be of the format HH:MM AM/PM with the date mentioned once only. Since tstpickelFile can have more than 50 entries, "2019-11-05T14:39:00.000-08:00" format will take over the entire chart.

This is the current result - https://i.stack.imgur.com/THQyF.jpg

Here is a sample image of how I would want the graph -  https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9D2b.jpg

Comment: Okay, so first of all `plt.savefig` should be after `plt.show` method. It's a convention we need to follow otherwise plot will be different than expected.

Comment: You need to show what you get when you try the code above. An error? An output that doesn't match your expectation?

Comment: @mayosten actually she needs to fill the
`time = []
count = []`
or else plot will be empty.

Comment: @Kirti Gupta What do you get when try 
```for key,value in Orderdict_variable.keys():
        print(key,value)
```

Comment: @Hayat I have added more info to the post

Comment: Since I added a lot of info, should I create this as a new post?

Comment: @KirtiGupta No, This is fine. Stackoverflow do not entertain redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

For split the time you can use string split like, I think this will solve your problem

```
for key, value in eachDict.items():
    if(key=="_time"):
            date, time = str(value).split("T")
            h, m, ex, ext = time.split(":")
            if h>12:
                val = str(h-12) + ":" + str(m) + " " + "PM"
            else:
                val = str(h) + ":" + str(m) + " " + "AM"
            time.append(val)
    if(key=="count"):
            count.append(value)
```

And for waving I'm researching it

Comment: That works! Now I need to figure the x-axis values which are coming as "711, 2823, 2731, 2752, 2581", but should be rather 0, 100, 200, 300, 400 (consistent intervals), so the graph is not a straight line (explained in the post)

Comment: But it is value, it is sowing the result increasing or decreasing , but why need limitation?

Comment: As mentioned in the post, the current graph shows like this -  https://imgur.com/DgG0j9U. But I want the graph to be shown like this (more like a statistics) - https://imgur.com/muczoUb

Comment: I have the result of your code, matplotlib automatic manage consistence intervals , I don't know why your code isn't showing in consistence, you can research

Comment: Can you share the exact code you are running on your machine?

Answer (score 0):

This is amazing just one line of code, it will be possible when the list is an sorted list,  I noticed that when the value of count sorted by ascending or descending in the list matplotlib automatic make consistence, so at first in loop

```
if(key=="count"):
        count.append(int(value))
```

and `count.sort()` on the top of plt.plot() definition
this will fix
right sub-code is:

```
for each in listcarr: 
    for key, value in each.items():
        if(key=="_time"):
            time.append(value)
        if(key=="count"):
            count.append(int(value))

count.sort()

plt.plot(time, count, '-', lw=2)
```

Comment: If you add sort to count, then the value of count corresponding to that specific time will change, which should not happen. For ex - At 2:39, count=711, At 2:40, count= 2823. But if you sort count, then At 2:39, count=655, At 2:40, count= 711, which is wrong data.

Comment: Previously I already told that it is real time data, when you ordering data will mismatched,

Comment: Instead of thinking anything you can just replace the last entry of every count from whatever to 0